# Segmentation fault in return index

Tags: c

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for(i=0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if(nums[j] == target - nums[i])
            {
                int *index = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
                index[0] = i;
                index[1] = j;
                return index;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I was writing the code for the following

Given `nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]`, `target = 9`,

Because `nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9`,
return `[0, 1]`.

I tried debugging the code, i and j values 0 and 1 as expected. But now I'am facing the issue while returning the index. It is showing as segmentation fault. Can anyone please correct the above code?

Comment: Run your program with `gdb` and then run `backtrace`. It will show you which line it is segfaulting on.

Comment: The `return index` instruction cannot possibly segfault. Your code looks right, there's no problem with it. You need to add a [mcve] to your question. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: your code is OK .. you have problem somewhere else. [my solution](https://onlinegdb.com/S1qJXbA-L)

Comment: I´ve seen you use `NULL` as return value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437282/can-i-use-null-as-substitution-for-the-value-of-0

Comment: @houssam I just saw your solution. But I didn't get what is purpose of typecasting malloc to void. Can you please explain?

Comment: @chayakumar : many compilers throw warning `Warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc` if you use `malloc` without including the header file: `#include <stdlib.h>`. but the code works !!. You can use it without casting such as `int *index = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);`. see :  [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/992406)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like codeforces or similar platform problems. Segmentation Fault is happening because you have not set `returnSize` passed by caller as same is required for freeing returned array. Thus solution would be to set `returnSize` to 2.

Comment: but `returnSize` still not being used inside the function. I'd consider to remove though.

Comment: @Muzol I agree. However, this code will be judged by 
online judge which requires `returnSize` as a param. That's just how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i=0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            printf("i=%d j=%d \n",i,j);
            if(nums[j] == target - nums[i])
            {
                int *index = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
                index[0] = i;
                index[1] = j;
                return index;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {2, 7, 11, 15}; // works
    //int * nums = {2, 7, 11, 15}; //compile OK (some compilers) but Segmentation fault .
    int target = 9;
    int * result = twoSum(nums,4,target,NULL);
    if(result)
        printf("result[0]=%d result[1]=%d" ,result[0] , result[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

- Your code is correct; but it depends on how you define `nums`; is it `array` or `pointer`?
- [Initializing array (pointer) with values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49041099/992406)
- [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/992406)